# Hiding / encrypting password in QGIS processing script

Tags: pyqgis, postgresql, qgis-processing, authentication

Is it possible to hide or encrypt password in QGIS processing script?

For example, hide password for PostgreSQL connection.

QGIS "Master password" is possible, but I need a solution for code of processing script.

Comment: What about this thread https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264298/hiding-password-of-postgis-layer-in-qgis-plugin ?